# Pasar información de formulario a otra pagina PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

quiero pasar la información de estos campos a otro archivo .php, pero el problema es de que como es una pasarela de pagos de un banco X no se permite colocar un botón, les muestro aquí el código:

```
<div class="card-body">
                  <select class="form-control" id="selectTipoDoc" name="tipoDocFac" onchange="vertipoFac();">
                    <option value="" id="seleccionarPrimero">Seleccionar</option>
                    <option value="Consumidor Final">Factura Consumidor Final</option>
                    <option value="Credito Fiscal">Credito Fiscal</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac1">
                    <label for="acc-email">Nombre Completo (Consumidor Final)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nombreConsumidorF' name='nombreConsumidorF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac2">
                    <label for="acc-email">DUI (Requerido)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='duiConsumidorF' name='duiConsumidorF' autocomplete="off" placeholder="00000000-0" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" style="font-weight: bold !important;" maxlength="10">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;"  id="txtFac3">
                    <label for="acc-email">Nombre De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nombreEmpresaCCF' name='nombreEmpresaCCF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac4">
                    <label for="acc-email">No. De Registro (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nRegistroCCF' name='nRegistroCCF' autocomplete="off" placeholder="" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" style="font-weight: bold !important;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac5">
                    <label for="acc-email">NIT De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nitEmpresaCCF' name='nitEmpresaCCF' autocomplete="off" placeholder="0000-000000-000-0" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" style="font-weight: bold !important;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;"  id="txtFac6">
                    <label for="acc-email">Giro De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='giroCCF' name='giroCCF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;"  id="txtFac7">
                    <label for="acc-email">Dirección De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='direccionEmpresaCCF' name='direccionEmpresaCCF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
                  </div>
                </div>
```

el div que el banco me proporciono el banco es el siguiente:

```
<div class="checkout-methods"> 
                <div id="paywayBtnContainer"></div>
            </div>
```

lamentablemente no puedo poner propiedades submit a ese div, es por eso mi pregunta, como guardo la información de ese formulario y se lo hago llegar a otra pagina, saludos.

Comment: Hola eso depende de como lo reciba el banco, sino puedes agregar las propiedades, simplemente envíalas en la url https://urldelbanco.com/?tipoDocFac=CC&txtFac1=pedro%lopez. Este es solo un ejemplo, ya que no brindas mucha información, pero tal vez te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Típicamente la información confidencial se envía por POST. En la consulta podrías agregar como se define el FORM que engloba a los inputs que quieres enviar y con ello podremos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un proceso en dos pasos, esto es, dos scripts PHP distintos:

1. Guarda los datos: esto es, procesa el formulario añadiendo los datos en tu base de datos.
2. Enlaza con la pasarela de pago: esto es, tras la inserción de los datos, inicia el proceso de pago.

Parece lo más sensato.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un elemento llamado Form en este elemento tenemos 2 metodos de transferencia de datos, POST y GET.
Para pasar los datos de todos tu input, puedes intentar esto.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="pagina2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="card-body">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectTipoDoc" name="tipoDocFac" onchange="vertipoFac();">
            <option value="" id="seleccionarPrimero">Seleccionar</option>
            <option value="Consumidor Final">Factura Consumidor Final</option>
            <option value="Credito Fiscal">Credito Fiscal</option>
        </select>
        <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac1">
            <label for="acc-email">Nombre Completo (Consumidor Final)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nombreConsumidorF' name='nombreConsumidorF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac2">
            <label for="acc-email">DUI (Requerido)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='duiConsumidorF' name='duiConsumidorF' autocomplete="off" placeholder="00000000-0" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" style="font-weight: bold !important;" maxlength="10">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac3">
            <label for="acc-email">Nombre De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nombreEmpresaCCF' name='nombreEmpresaCCF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac4">
            <label for="acc-email">No. De Registro (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nRegistroCCF' name='nRegistroCCF' autocomplete="off" placeholder="" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" style="font-weight: bold !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac5">
            <label for="acc-email">NIT De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nitEmpresaCCF' name='nitEmpresaCCF' autocomplete="off" placeholder="0000-000000-000-0" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" style="font-weight: bold !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac6">
            <label for="acc-email">Giro De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='giroCCF' name='giroCCF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required-field" style="display: none;" id="txtFac7">
            <label for="acc-email">Dirección De La Empresa (Crédito Fiscal)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id='direccionEmpresaCCF' name='direccionEmpresaCCF' autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;font-weight: bold !important;">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```